# How to download large files on slow, bad connectivity networks?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, download, nsurlsession

My app is downloading large 90 MB video files from a server. Many customers in rural areas complain about inability to download them. Downloads always restart from scratch when the connection breaks for too long.

Is there a library that can download large files in very low and interrupted bandwidth conditions over the course of several days if necessary? Such that it resumes an unfinished download and keeps adding bit by bit until it is complete?

It has to be very, very robust.

Answer (score 1):

NSURLSession supports this. When a download fails you can obtain an object that can be used to resume the download later. Read [the doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLSession/downloadTaskWithResumeData:) for more infos.

You can also make use of a background session if you want to perform a long download in the background. See [the doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionConfiguration_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLSessionConfiguration/backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:) and this question : [NSURLSession background download - resume over network failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184490/nsurlsession-background-download-resume-over-network-failure)

Comment: I recall reading about a bug with NSURLSession that caused downloads to fail forever, for a particular file. Any words on this? And do you know of a library that uses NSURLSession and takes care of all the nitty gritty details to manage a download and display progress?

Comment: Never heard of that bug, but I'm not using NSURLSession a lot so I wouldn't know. As for a NSURLSession manager that takes care of restarting downloads automatically I don't have one in mind sorry.

Comment: Start here : https://github.com/search?l=Objective-C&o=desc&q=download+manager&s=stars&type=Repositories